# How to prevent Liferay from prepending theme portlet path in my images in CSS

Tags: plugins, themes, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I developed a theme plugin in Liferay 6.2. In my css files, I use this to reference images:

```
background-image: url('../images/main_bck.jpg');
```

It works perfectly in my local machine, but after I deployed it on our staging server it is showing different path and so my images are not showing properly:

```
background-image: url("/express-portal-theme/css//express-portal-theme/css/../images/main_bck.jpg");
```

I've not yet found any solution in google. Please help.

Cheers!
Rio

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing it to:

```
background-image: url('/express-portal-theme/images/main_bck.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage to fix it, the problem is due to nested file includes:

In my `docroot/_diff/css/custom.css` I included these imports:

```
@import url(express-portal.css);

@import url(fonts.css);

@import url(frontend_login.css);

@import url(frontend_landing.css);
```

and in my `docroot/css/main.css`:

```
@import url(base.css);

@import url(application.css);

@import url(layout.css);

@import url(dockbar.css);

@import url(navigation.css);

@import url(portlet.css);

@import url(extras.css);

@import url(custom.css);
```

So, I modify `main.css` to include all my custom css files and then it works!

```
My modified main.css looks like this:

@import url(base.css);

@import url(application.css);

@import url(layout.css);

@import url(dockbar.css);

@import url(navigation.css);

@import url(portlet.css);

@import url(extras.css);

@import url(express-portal.css);

@import url(fonts.css);

@import url(frontend_login.css);

@import url(frontend_landing.css);
```